# WC REST Payment - Stripe Gateway' is not available

Tags: api

I installed the plugin and I could not configure it with stripe I get this error.

{"code":407,"message":"Failed to process payment. WooCommerce Gateway 'stripe' exists, but 'WC REST Payment - Stripe Gateway' is not available.","data":{"status":400}}

Comment: [The documentation says](https://docs.wc-rest-payment.com/gateways/stripe/) "For installation, install & activate [WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/) and WC REST Payment - Stripe Gateway from you wp-admin Dashboard." You've definitely done all that?

Comment: But if you have, you'll probably do better asking on [the plugin support forums](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-rest-payment/) or the email address on that page. You're more likely to find an expert on this plugin there.

Comment: I do not know what it is.    WC REST Payment - Stripe Gateway   I look for it as a plugin etc and nothing appears.